# Unable to access Lacie NAS from some network locations

Tags: networking, vmware, nas

I have a Lacie 2Big NAS (have had for a while now), and I have just gone to re-purpose it, meaning it needs to be accessed by client desktop/laptops in my house (previously only used by VMWare servers).

I have found that PCs cannot access the NAS via SMB (or even the HTTP web interface), I get a "The network path was not found" error. However, all the servers running on my VMWare machine can access the NAS without issue.

I will briefly explain my setup, please let me know if you need any more info.

I have a modem/router, connected to a Netgear unmanaged gigabit switch. Everything is connected to this switch (including the VMWare host machine). Some PCs are connected via WiFi, but a few of the machines in particular that I need to get working are connected via Ethernet to the same switch.

I have tried using DNS name, FQDN, and IP address - all result in the same response.

Comment: Firewalls all configured properly?

Comment: Firewalls are turned off via GPO within my domain/network. In any case, all machines have the same firewall policy, including the ones that DO work with the NAS :(